# jquery apply addClass to link only if link text is in array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array:

```
var List2 = ['Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'New Jersey', 'Oklahoma'];
```

I have php generated table rows with links in them, with class .one on each link.

```
<a class="one" href="http://www.maine.gov/aPage.shtml">Maine</a>
<a class="one" href="https://www.colorado.gov/aPage.aspx">Colorado</a>
```

Upon clicking the link, the goal is to open a div if the state in the link text is in the array (eg. Maine), but to open the link if the state in the link text is not in the array (eg. Colorado)

To do that I want to add a class, .openDiv, only to those whose link text appears in the array. .openDiv will then be used to open the div.

I'm iterating (I think) using each() to find all links with text in the array and apply the openDiv.

Both links are working correctly when I test them manually, but my addClass code is applying .openDiv to every link in the list and I don't know how to limit that to just those in the array. My .js script is at the bottom of the page.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{var List2 = ['Idaho', 'District of Columbia', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'New Jersey', 'Oklahoma'];

$("a[href]").each(function() {
if(jQuery.inArray($("a[href]").html(), List2) !== -1) {
$("a[href]").addClass('openDiv');
}
});
$(".openDiv").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#notInList1").slideToggle(200);
});
 });
```

I've tried

```
$("a[href]").text()
```

and various forms of $this, but no go. I've read 3 or 4 other questions but none are the same. 
Does anyone know how I should be using $this to fix it, or is my each() function screwed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `a[href]` elements when adding the class. Instead use the `this` keyword in the `each()` handler to add the class to the current element only:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var List2 = ['Idaho', 'District of Columbia', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'New Jersey', 'Oklahoma'];

  $("a[href]").each(function() {
    if (List2.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1) {
      $(this).addClass('openDiv'); // note 'this' here
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.openDiv { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="one" href="http://www.maine.gov/aPage.shtml">Maine</a>
<a class="one" href="https://www.colorado.gov/aPage.aspx">Colorado</a>
```

Comment: Well I thought so too, but with that, it doesn't add the .openDiv at all.

Comment: just saw your extended reply. Let me look further

Comment: Ok, great, please alter your code to say List2 instead of list and I'll mark yours as the accepted answer. And thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Glad to help. I changed it - but you should note that that variable name doesn't follow JS naming conventions.

Comment: should I use list for the array?

Comment: You can use whatever you like, but it should really be lower camel cased.